# Uploading MVC Website and MySQL to Webhost

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, file-upload, web-hosting, filezilla

I created a website using Code Ignitor and MySQL and want to upload everything to 000webhost.com

How do I:

1. upload my models, views and controllers to the public_html folder of 000webhost?
2. get my MySQL database up and running on 000webhost?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am presuming that your control panel is cPanel. If thats the case then upload all your files in the web root of the server. Create a database, and change that details in database.php inside config folder. thats it, your site will be up and running.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Upload all files (controllers, models and views) in the public_html folder of 000webhost?

Comment: I also created an .htaccess file in the root of my CodeIgnitor file which will eliminate the need for the index.php in the urls. Should I also put this in the root as well

Answer (score 0):

Your .htaccess (at least mod_rewrite for codeigniter) will not work if you use the free 000webhost service (at least the last time i wanted it, the support told me that they doesn't support it... that was thy time i signed up for their free service for private test of scripts i wrote). Another thing is that for the free hosting they use their own control panel (not cPanel), cPanel is for the paid accounts.
Anyway they both offer ftp accounts, mysql databases and of course web ftp (online file manager). All you need is a ftp client (such as FileZilla or even Windows Explorer itself).